# Can I just rig my high poly model instead of having to retopologize it?

Tags: rigging

I'm creating a project for a class I am taking; it's a character model. It's pretty stylized, and I spent over a week working on it, and it's due soon. Currently it's at 180,000 Verts, 350,000 Faces, 370,000 Tris. How many hurdles would I run into trying to rig this model for animation?

I just started "Retopologizing" the model, and I can tell it's going to be very time-consuming. I'd rather just attempt to rig the model as it currently is. I don't really understand why it's so difficult. If I'm careful, is it really that big of a deal? Tips and advice much appreciated.

Comment: There are a whole bunch of factors that might determine if that amount of faces is workable, it's hard to advise without knowing a bunch more about both your setup and your "desired presentation environment" such as how you plan the final animation to play (in blender? as a rendered movie? how close to the camera is the object? etc...) . Have you tried using the decimate modifier for your retopo? It's possible It could make quick work of it.

Comment: For the class assignment, I don’t have any plans to fully render it (image or animation). I mostly just want to able to playback within Blender as I am animating it. I may retopologize the model later if I plan to do more with it.

I have tried the Decimate modifier, and I don’t know many Iterations I’d have to apply, but I’m currently at 50 and it lowered the poly mount by a few digits, but it noticeably lost some detail.

Comment: I just learned of a program called “Instant Meshes” that does the retopology automatically, but I don’t know how comfortable I am using third-party software completely separate from Blender. With that one, it looks like I’d have to export my model as a .obj, use Instant Meshes, and bring it back into Blender.

Comment: There are several good operations and tools for reducing poly count, but keep in mind that for a class, the instructor may be looking for specific topology features like proper poles and junctions. It would be a good idea to try several options, then finalize the one that works best for you.